# NSSortDescriptor JSON feed UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, uitableview

I have my JSON feed mapped using rest kit and displaying nicely in my `UITableView`. I would like to sort the cells of the tableView with `NSSortDescriptor` (I think?), based on a 'Double' mapped from the json feed called 'Temp'

My code for the NSSortDescriptor so far is

```
NSSortDescriptor *tempSortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"temp" ascending:YES];
weatherObjects = [weatherObjects sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:@[tempSortDescriptor]];
```

But not sure if it is correct or if I need to put it right after my RKResponseDescriptor or in tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath? (maybe neither?)

Answer (score 0):

Do the sorting after you have retrieved all your objects from JSON feed and before it is displayed by the UITableView. When the array is sorted then use that array as your data source in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` and get the appropriate object. You probably need to make the `weatherObjects` array a property of your class.

```
@property (nonatomic) NSArray *weatherObjects;
```

So in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`:

```
anObject = [self.weatherObjects objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

**Update based on OP comments:**
OK. So lets say you have two objects. I called the type MyMain. Each of those as a double variable called temp. And you have an array that has those two objects in it.

```
MyMain *m1 = [MyMain new];
m1.temp = 2.0;

MyMain *m2 = [MyMain new];
m2.temp = 1.0;

NSArray *myObjects = @[m1, m2];

NSArray *sortedArray = [myObjects sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(id obj1, id obj2) {
    MyMain *o1 = obj1;
    MyMain *o2 = obj2;
    NSComparisonResult result = [[NSNumber numberWithDouble:o1.temp] compare:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:o2.temp]];

    return result;
}];

MyMain *s1 = sortedArray[0];
MyMain *s2 = sortedArray[1];

NSLog(@"First Object temp: %f and second object temp: %f", s1.temp, s2.temp);
```

This print object with temp value of 1.0 first and 2.0 second.

Comment: i'm a bit confused, i have made weatherObjects an array and set objectAtIndex:indexPath.ro.. Should i use the sort descriptor in viewdidload after my JSON requests? 'temp' is a double and its in its own class called 'main'.  I'm wondering if in my NSSortDescriptor initWithKey:@"temp" is not finding the value to sort it by?

Comment: If the tableView is not loaded you can use `viewDidLoad` but if it is then you need to reload the tableView. For sorting the way you have created it, it assumes that weatherObjects has a variable called `temp`. If that's not the case it won't find it. You can probably access it through `keyPath` instead of `key`.

Comment: temp is with an object in weatherArray(weatherObjects) but it is within an object called 'main' then within main it is 'temp', i wasn't reloading my tableview data but i'm still not getting it to sort.  Could you give me some sample code fro 'keyPath' please?

Comment: Updated answer based on your comment.